# How to make button non transparent?

Tags: android, styles, transparency, z-order

I wrote custom View which draws a circle. Then I put it on relative layout. Also I put standard button there, so that they overlap. And I see that button is transparent. How to make it non transparent?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard Holo themed button is partially transparent. You can either create a new button 9.png image to use in the button or create a new button by using drawable.

Here's a link on how to do the latter:

http://droidapp.co.uk/?p=309

Comment: What is the simplest way? Can't I just style button as not transparent?

Comment: The second option is quite straight forward. You can just change the background of the button to a solid color (ie #999999) but that would not look good and wouldn't give the button a pressed state causing bad user experience.

Answer (score 31):

Set the background to `@android:drawable/btn_default` to get rid of the transparency of holo theme

Comment: This also changes the graphic to the device default (i.e. not holo).

Comment: It's the perfect answer! Do you know how to apply it to another controls? (especially to EditText)

Comment: All right, I've found the answer to my question by myself, it is: @android:drawable/edit_text

Answer (score 2):

you can put the button in seperate Frame Layout so that your view wont affect the button and thats my idea

Answer (score 1):

save below code as xml in drawable folder and give this xml as button background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    <corners android:radius="1px"/>
    <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="3dp" android:right="5dp" android:bottom="3dp" /> 
</shape>
```

Ex:

```
android:background="@drawable/<< your file name>>"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem but with ToggleButton. A ugly but fast solution was to position a ImageView right behind the button and change its `margin`s, `background` and `alpha` to fit the button. For example, inside a RelativeLayout:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toggleButton"
    style="@style/HackBackgroundToggleButton" />

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    ... />
```

And, in an effort to reduce the visible hack, the extracted style:

```
<style name="HackBackgroundToggleButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">84dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">42dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:alpha">0.75</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The holo transparency is actually built into the PNG files. So the only real way to change it is to edit the PNGs and make them non-transparent. This is actually not easy at all. You need to multiply the alpha channel of the image by 255/102. Which isn't easy!

But because I am such a genius, I found a way to do it. Basically I copied all the relevant PNGs and XMLs into their own directory structure (the buttons only have `-mdpi`, `-hdpi` and `-xhdpi` versions). Then I ran this:

for FILE in `find . -name *.png`; do mogrify -evaluate Multiply 2.5 -channel Alpha $FILE ; done

Job done! Actually it didn't quite work for the disabled buttons for some reason - I think because the centre is super-transparent, but I don't care so much about those. You'll have to use a higher value than 2.5 for those images if you want them totally non-transparent.

Anway the result is [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxBsaeNc0igKQ0pjdTJyenBqTjg).

Comment: This is excellent, but when you say "Then I ran this...", where do you run that code from?